# Why does unregistering an notification receiver in -dealloc create an infinite loop under ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, concurrency, automatic-ref-counting

I have an NSOperation subclass which uses Core Data.

It has a custom init method like this:

```
- (id)initWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc;
```

As you may know, Core Data managed object contexts are not thread-safe and every thread needs it's own managed object context. When creating this NSOperation, I create a new NSManagedObjectContext and pass it as the `moc` argument to the initializer.

**Here's the important part:** When initializing, I register for a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:)  name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:moc];
```

In `-dealloc` I unregister from the NotificationCenter:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:nil object:nil];
}
```

Before I migrated to ARC, this code worked perfectly fine.

---

Now under ARC, I get a stack trace like this:

1) The NSOperation object receives -dealloc

2) -removeObserver:name:object: is called on the NSNotificationCenter.

3) __arclite_objc_release

---

4) The NSOperation object receives -dealloc

5) -removeObserver:name:object: is called on the NSNotificationCenter.

6) __arclite_objc_release

---

7) The NSOperation object receives -dealloc

8) -removeObserver:name:object: is called on the NSNotificationCenter.

9) __arclite_objc_release

---

This continues forever. -dealloc, unregister from notification center, __arclite_objc_release, -dealloc, ...

It seems like if __arclite_objc_release triggeres a call to -dealloc even though the NSOperation object has been destroyed!

How is this possible?

**Update:** For some insanely weird reason the infinite loop to -dealloc disappeared after I changed my notification center unregistration code to this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:nil object:self.managedObjectContext];
```

So instead of simply unregistering for any notification sent by *any* sender, I explicitely unregister for any notification sent by a *particular* sender.

The obvious problem is this: Since ARC inserts code into -dealloc, I don't know if it is inserted *before* my -dealloc code, or *after* my -dealloc code.

Comment: What happens if you say `__autoreleasing __typeof__(self) _self = self; [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:_self name:nil object:nil]`?

Comment: Sniffs of a bug to me. I thought the dealloc code knew if it was already dealloc-ing so it wouldn't go through the process again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reading your update, it seems you should call `[super dealloc]` in a different place than where you are (if you are). Try calling it first thing in the dealloc method, then unregister your `NSNotification`

Comment: He's using ARC though. So he can't call super's dealloc.